# Completion handler swift 3 return a variable from function

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, completionhandler

I am confused surrounding the syntax for a completion handler in swift 3.

In the function below, after parsing an `xml` file from a web service call, it should return a variable (an `array [String:String]`).
My attempt is below, but obviously it is incorrect.

```
  enum HistoryKey {
  case success([String:String])
  case failure(String)
 }

 private func getHistoryKeys(searchterm: String, completion: @escaping () -> HistoryKey) {
    let url = PubmedAPI.createEsearchURL(searchString: searchterm)
    let request = URLRequest.init(url: url as URL)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let theData = data{
            let myParser = XMLParser.init(data: theData)
            myParser.delegate = self
            myParser.parse()
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    if keys.isEmpty {
        return .failure("no historyKeyDictionary")
    }else{
        return .success(keys)
    }

}// End of func
```

I want to use this function as follows

```
 let result = self.getHistoryKeys(searchTerm)
```

Comment: @EricAya he is not trying to return the value from the function, but rather pass it on to another completion handler.

Comment: Your right. I didn't notice that. @EricAya

Comment: Accept answer please, to let others to find it faster. Thanks. Press jackdaw

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two issues:

- The completion handler passes a `HistoryKey` instance and has no return value so the signature must be the other way round.
- The call of the completion handler must be **inside** the completion block of the data task.

---

To be able to parse the received data outside the completion block return the `data` on success

```
enum ConnectionResult {
   case success(Data)
   case failure(Error)
}

private func getHistoryKeys(searchterm: String, completion: @escaping (ConnectionResult) -> ()) {
   let url = PubmedAPI.createEsearchURL(searchString: searchterm)
   let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
       if let error = error {
          completion(.failure(error))
       } else {
          completion(.success(data!))
       }
  }
  task.resume()
}
```

and call it

```
getHistoryKeys(searchterm: String) { connectionResult in 
    switch connectionResult {
       case .success(let data): 
           let myParser = XMLParser(data: data)
           myParser.delegate = self
           myParser.parse()
           // get the parsed data from the delegate methods

       case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i have just added an edit to give an idea on how i would like to use the function.  Would your solution work for above?

Comment: No it does not. Either you have to return the received `Data` because the parser works asynchronously and parse the XML outside the function or you have to assign the completion handler to a variable to get a strong reference and call the completion handler from the XMLParser delegate method. Btw: your *array* in the enum case is a dictionary.

Comment: PS: I updated the answer to pass the received data in the completion handler. Put the code to handle the result of the XML parser into the parser delegate method.

Comment: I understand your solution - obtaining the variable from the delegate method e.g parserDidEndDocument.  But, could you show me how to call the completion handler from parserDidEndDocument for instance?

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `completion` block.
Use it like:

```
private func getHistoryKeys(searchterm: String, completion: @escaping (_ keys: Array) -> Void) {
    //do the magic
    completion(keys)
}
```

Then you can call this function as:

```
getHistoryKeys(searchterm: "str") { (keys) in 
    print("\(keys)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

```
enum HistoryKey {
    case success([String:String])
    case failure(String)
}

func myFunction(str: String, completionHandler: @escaping (HistoryKey) -> ()){
     completion(.success([String:String]))
     //OR
     completion(.failure(""))
}

myFunction(str: String) { result in 
    switch result {
       case .success(let data): break;
       case .failure(let error): break;
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
func myFunction(str: String, completionHandler: @escaping (String) -> ()){
     completionHandler("")
} 

myFunction(str: "someThing", completionHandler: {(str) in

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the result as an argument in the completion handler:

```
private func getHistoryKeys(searchterm: String, completion: @escaping (result: HistoryKey) -> Void) {
    let url = PubmedAPI.createEsearchURL(searchString: searchterm)
    let request = URLRequest.init(url: url as URL)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let theData = data{
            let myParser = XMLParser.init(data: theData)
            myParser.delegate = self
            myParser.parse()
        }

        //DispatchQueue.main.async { // if you want to do UI stuff dispatch calls to completion() on the main queue
        if keys.isEmpty {
            completion(.failure("no historyKeyDictionary"))
        } else{
            completion(.success(keys))
        }
        //}
    }
    task.resume()   
}
```

And call it like this:

```
getHistoryKeys("searchMe") { (result: HistoryKey) in
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i have just added an edit to give an idea on how i would like to use the function.  Would your solution work for above? because your return value is void

Comment: No. `self.getHistoryKeys(searchTerm)` returns immediately, but your download takes time. You have to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it should be

```
private func getHistoryKeys(searchterm: String, completion: @escaping (HistoryKey) -> ())
```

Also `completion(.failure("no historyKeyDictionary"))` or `completion(.success(keys))` should be used instead of `return`

Answer (score 0):

```
 enum HistoryKey {
    case success([String: String])
    case failure(String)
 }

 private func getHistoryKeys(searchterm: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: HistoryKey) -> Void) {
    let url = PubmedAPI.createEsearchURL(searchString: searchterm)
    let request = URLRequest.init(url: url as URL)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let theData = data{
            let myParser = XMLParser.init(data: theData)
            myParser.delegate = self
            myParser.parse()
        }

        if keys.isEmpty {
            completion(.failure("no historyKeyDictionary"))
        } else {
            completion(.success(keys))
        }
    }
    task.resume()    
} // End of func
```

Something like that. Change `@escaping` declaration and do a completion instead of return.

Hope it helps.